# Flask How can I do change for specific users

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I am new to flask and I try to do a project that you do signup and if the admin press a button next to your name then the home page for the user will change.
Here is the code of flask:

```
from flask import Flask,redirect,url_for,render_template,request,flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager,UserMixin,login_required,login_user,logout_user,current_user
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired,Length
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abc'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=True,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=True,nullable=False)
    
db.create_all()

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Username',validators=[InputRequired(),Length(min=4,max=30,message='Name must be from 7 to 30')])
    password = PasswordField('Password',validators=[InputRequired(),Length(min=4,max=30,message='Password must be from 7 to 30')])


users = []
@app.route("/",methods=['POST','GET'])
def home():
    form = RegisterForm()
    try:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = Users(name=form.name.data,password=form.password.data)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            users.append(form.name.data)
            return redirect('/home')
    except:
        return 'Name doest exist'
    return render_template("register.html",form=form)

#You don't have now to log in to be admin
#For the Project only


a = 3
@app.route("/admin",methods=['POST','GET'])
def admin():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        global a
        a = 2
    return render_template("new3.html",mylist=users)
@app.route("/home")
def home1():
    return render_template("new4.html",r=a)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And for the new3.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        {%for i in mylist%}
            <p>{{i}}</p>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <button name='button1'>Press it</button>
            </form>
        {%endfor%}
    </body>
```

So how can I do that?
I just want the change of home page to be only to the user that button pressed.
I tried to do that by sending from email but I want to the change be on the home page.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you describe is built into HTML: The **O**rdered **L**list. With some template code like:

```
<body>
  <ol>
    {% for b in bros %}
      <li>{{b}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ol>
<body>
```

Renders in the browser like:

[image: rendered]

You need not manually deal with the count in your template, and items will appear in the HTML list in the same order as the python list `myList` (as python lists are ordered by default).